# Fetching List from another class (Android)

Tags: android, arraylist

Okay, I searched here already and tried to understand existing questions but had difficulty so I'm posting this.
In my app cards are shown using a recyclerview. When user clicks any item, its index (int i) is passed to the CardViewActivity and it displays the card matching the value. 
I'm trying to show data on Cards from a List<>. I've no issues if I keep it in the same file. But, I want to keep it in a different, common file and access it from other classes. My current code is going in to loop I guess and I'm not able to see what it is exactly.

Please help.

My Person.class is:

```
class Person {
String name;
String age;
int photoId;
List<Person> persons;

Person(String name, String age, int photoId) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.photoId = photoId;
}
protected void initializePerson(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));
    CardViewActivity cardViewActivity = new CardViewActivity(persons, this);
    cardViewActivity.setDetails();

}
}
```

I'm trying to access it from CardViewActivity:

```
public class CardViewActivity extends Activity {

TextView personName;
TextView personAge;
ImageView personPhoto;
List<Person> persons;
Person person;
int id;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getIntExtra("position", 0);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Message"+id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Person person = new Person();
    person.initializePerson();

    setContentView(R.layout.cardview_activity);
    personName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.person_name);
    personAge = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.person_age);
    personPhoto = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.person_photo);
    //personName.setText(persons.get(0).name);
    setDetails();

}

CardViewActivity(List<Person> persons, Person person){
    this.persons = persons;
    this.person = person;
}
public void setDetails(){
//this.persons = persons;
//Toast.makeText(this, "Inside setDetails() and id is "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//Toast.makeText(this, "Person name is "+persons.get(i).name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
int i = id;
personName.setText(persons.get(i).name);
//personAge.setText(persons.get(i).age);
//personPhoto.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);

}

private void initializeData(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.emma));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.lavery));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.lillie));


}
}
```

Comment: Can you make the list static?

Comment: Depending on what you are going for you can make the list of cards static.  You can put it in a separate class, and access it from other classes like Class.cardList

Comment: I guess that's what I'm doing. I'm putting it inside class Person. I want to access it for RecyclverView in another class as well but first I'm trying with single cards.

Answer (score 0):

Do following

```
public class SomeConstant {
    public static List<String> someList = new ArrayList<String>();
    static {
        someList.add("John");
        someList.add("adam");
    }
}
```

//here you will call the list you created 
    public class SomeClass {

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(SomeConstant.someList);
    }

}
```

Comment: and what would be the advantage of this?

Comment: not necessorily you have to do as above ... in your code you can define list as public static and you should be able to access in other class